# Getting the value of a property

Tags: javascript

[image]

How do I get the value of `BrandID`?

Comment: Is this about getting a property, or about looping over all properties?

Comment: Getting a property value.

Comment: How about showing us what you've tried?

Comment: Why is it titled looping them?

Comment: I tried, console.log(data.Item[0].BrandID);

Comment: Try data[0].Item.BrandID

Comment: I down-voted for the level of lazy.  This is something you could have easily found through a google search.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `yourObjectArray[0].Item.BrandID`

Comment: yourObjectArray[0].Item.BrandID I think.

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
objRef[0]["Item"]["BrandID"]
```

or you can use:

```
objRef[0].Item.BrandID
```

For Iterating in your array you will use:

```
var i;
for(i=0; i < objRef.Length ; i++)
{
    var brandId = objRef[i].Item.BrandID;
    // or
    var brandId = objRef[i]["Item"]["BrandID"];

    // your code blocks to process blockId
}
```

Comment: Why do it in bracket notation?

Comment: It is just an example. You can use it in either way.
Using Bracket notation helps in some cases.

Comment: Example or not, it's not where you'd use it.

Comment: Those cases being when the key name is unknown.

Comment: Correct. When key name is unknown or changes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this ..

```
ObjectArray[0].Item.BrandID
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
for(var i = 0, len = yourObjectArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    var youNeed = yourObjectArray[i].Item.BrandID;
}
```